# glDebugMessageCallback doesn't get called despite of error

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, error-handling

I am using GLFW and GLEW in a C++ program to work with OpenGL. I want to be able to output OpenGL errors to the console. To test this, I made a little program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// Test error function
void GLAPIENTRY MessageCallback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam) {
    std::cout << "ERROR";
}

// Main function
int main(void)
{
    // Just some initialization
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Debugtest", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();

    // Output the opengl version
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    // Enable debug output
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glDebugMessageCallback(MessageCallback, 0);

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(-1, &buffer); // -1 throws an error according to http://docs.gl/gl4/glGenBuffers

    // Loop until the user closes the window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    };

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The code for the callback is from [the khronos documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output). `glGenBuffers` should throw an error acccording to [the docs](http://docs.gl/gl4/glDebugMessageCallback). However, the OpenGL window stays white, the terminal just displays the OpenGL version (`4.5.13474 Copatibility Profile Context 22.19.162.4`).

What is the best way to handle errors? How do I fix my code?

Comment: Do you request an OpenGL debug context? Otherwise the error callback will never be called.

Comment: Have you trued using  ```glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);``` before calling ```glCreateWindow()```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @OutOfBound I found the answer. Before `glfwCreateWindow`, you need to call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE)`.

Similar to his answer, you can do something like this to break when an error occurs (At least using the MSVC compiler):

```cpp
#define call(x) x;\
    if (error) __debugbreak();

bool error = false;

void GLAPIENTRY MessageCallback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam) {
    error = true;
    std::cout << "[OpenGL Error](" << type << ") " << message << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my OpenGL projects I wrap every call into the OpenGL API with error checking. My approach goes something like this:

```
std::string error_description(GLenum err) {
    switch(err) {
        case GL_NO_ERROR:
            return "GL_NO_ERROR: No error has been recorded. The value of this symbolic constant is guaranteed to be 0. ";
        case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
            return "GL_INVALID_ENUM: An unacceptable value is specified for an enumerated argument. The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag.  ";
        case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "GL_INVALID_VALUE: A numeric argument is out of range. The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag.  ";
        case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
            return "GL_INVALID_OPERATION: The specified operation is not allowed in the current state. The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag.  ";
        case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
            return
            "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: The framebuffer object is not complete."
            "The offending command is ignored and has no other side effect than to set the error flag.";
        case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
            return "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY: There is not enough memory left to execute the command. The state of the GL is undefined, except for the state of the error flags, after this error is recorded. . ";
        case GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW:
            return "GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW: An attempt has been made to perform an operation that would cause an internal stack to underflow. ";
        case GL_STACK_OVERFLOW:
            return "GL_STACK_OVERFLOW: An attempt has been made to perform an operation that would cause an internal stack to overflow. ";
        default:
            return "No Description";
    }
}

namespace detail {
    void check() {
        const auto err = glGetError();
        if(err != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            throw std::runtime_error(error_description(err));
        }
    }

}


template <class result_t, class... gl_args_t, class... args_t>
result_t call(result_t (*fun)(gl_args_t...), args_t... args) {
    if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<result_t, void>) {
        auto result = fun(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
        #ifndef NDEBUG
            detail::check();
        #endif
        return result;
    } else {
        fun(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
        #ifndef NDEBUG
            detail::check();
        #endif
    }
}
```

In the application I call into the API like this:

```
call(<api_call>, <arguments...>>);
call(glGenBuffers, 1, &buffer);
```

The reasons, why I prefer the error checking over the error callback:

- Unhandled exceptions will terminate your program and make it easy to identify the exact line of code that is broken
- If you are consequent and wrap all calls to OpenGL, then you know that your state machine is always in a defined state

Comment: How does this answer the question? Op already has a debug callback which does basically the same as your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying a similar approach right now, but a callback seems more elegant to me.